# windows azure adds +10 hours to time field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We have an asp.net mvc application that is hosted on windows azure as a cloud service. We are having an issue when storing date time.

The site uses telerik controls.

Basically we have a start datetime field and an end datetime field that we enter in a pop-up dialog. If I enter in to this field for example 31/08/2013 06:00 AM for the start and 31/08/2013 07:00 AM for the end then press save it displays in a telerik grid, but it has added 10 hours to each field, I am presuming because Brisbane Australia, where I am is + 10 hours.

I then save the data and it stores in the database as the time that has + 10 hours. The time being entered is not relevant to a time zone we just want whatever time entered to be the time entered, regardless of where the user is etc.

Answer (score 2):

**`Windows Azure datacenters run in UTC time zone`**. That's the reason (and as you have guessed) you see a 10 hour time difference. One possible (and recommended) solution could be to make us e of UTC times always in your application. That way no matter from where your application is accessed, you get a consistent behavior in your application as far as date/time is concerned. In this scenario when the user enters any date/time you assume that to be in UTC.

Another thing you could do is pass the user's time zone to your server side logic and convert the date/time provided by the user into UTC time zone. So if a user from Australia provides a start date/time of 31/08/2013 06:00 AM, you also pass the timezone user is in and on the server side you would convert this date/time to UTC based on user's provided date/time and user's time zone.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks very much for your answer. It is as I understood, and yes one solution would be to consider the users time zone and code for the offset. However in this situation it is time against an object (the location of a store) as oppose to the user that is important. The only way around it I see is that we will have to use strings for data entry and display and handle the time setting in business logic away from the ui. Australia has several time zones and relating each store to a time zone is far too complex for what is needed. I believe you should be able to set a time as a time.

Comment: One thing you would need to keep in mind is when you construct date/time object from that string because again the date/time would be converted into UTC on the server. One thing you could do is construct just date part first based on the string and then append time separately to the date you just created.